# How to make a simple celsius to farenheit conversion table within a specific range of temperatures in PYTHON?

Tags: python, for-loop, if-statement, range

Blockquote

[1]I have not seen an answer for python. Not sure how to display a table.

I tried a for loop for the range and am stuck on displaying in a table.

[How would I be able to display my numbers like this][2]

> }

```
celsius = 0

for i in range (20,50):
    farenheit = celsius*(9/5)+32
print ()
```

{
[2]: https://i.stack.imgur.com/yP60v.png

Comment: Welcome to SO! Please show us your attempt!

Comment: Please share the code you have, and explain where you're stuck, what you're getting and what you were expecting to get.

Comment: Converting celsius to fahrenheit is a simple matter of multiplication.  Surely you know how to multiply numbers in Python?

Comment: _I tried a for loop for the range_ If you don't show us the code you tried, we can't point out what you did wrong.

Comment: There you go sorry I am new to this forum.

Comment: Do you want the results in one column or many?

Comment: just those two columns. a conversion table basically within the ranges of 20,50

Comment: What do you think you are printing?  You are printing nothing, and you are doing it outside of the loop.  If you want something printed for each loop, you need to do it inside.

Comment: yes i understand I am stuck on how to print the table I am not sure where to go from there.

Answer (score 0):

First off, there are a multitude of ways one might approach producing a table such as this.  The following snippet of code is just one way and probably isn't even the most elegant way to do this.

```
low = int(input("Enter the low temparature starting point in Degrees Celcius: "))
high = int(input("Enter the high temparature starting point in Degrees Celcius: "))

print(f"{'Celcius'.ljust(12)}{'Fahrenheit'.ljust(11)}")

for i in range(low, high + 1):
    fahrenheit = int(i * (9/5) + 32)
    print(str(i).ljust(11), str(fahrenheit).ljust(7))
```

Some points to note.

- Instead of hard coding in a range for the loop to process, a low and high number is being prompted.
- To provide some rudimentary formatting, the values are converted into string variables which allows for some justification of the data.

With those bits in place, following was a simple test of the code.

```
@Dev:~/Python_Programs/Temperature$ python3 Temperature.py 
Enter the low temparature starting point in Degrees Celcius: 40
Enter the high temparature starting point in Degrees Celcius: 50
Celcius     Fahrenheit 
40          104    
41          105    
42          107    
43          109    
44          111    
45          113    
46          114    
47          116    
48          118    
49          120    
50          122
```

You might want to reference the following link for more information on justifying data [Python justification](https://www.geeksforgeeks.org/python-string-ljust-rjust-center)

Feel free to experiment with other methods, but give this a try to see if it meets the spirit of the project.